# monotouch UITableView SectionIndexTitles brakes custom cell's background

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm experiencing really strange issue with monotouch SectionIndex side panel. Basically after adding

**public override string[] SectionIndexTitles (UITableView tableView)**

to my table data source, I can see side index being correctly populated, although it cuts a bit of my custom cell's background, which makes it look a bit weird (see image below)

I've got **UITableView.Appearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear** set in AppearanceManager, which by look of it, SectionIndex inherits, although what I want is to get SectionIndex to stay "on top" without affecting anything below it including my cell's background image.

Am I missing some property that needs to be applied to UITableView?

I spent ages trying to figure out what's missing, but not getting anywhere with it...

Thanks!

screenshot - http://blue-and-orange.net/media/30659/untitled.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the problem!

Background should not be assigned directly on cell's BackgroundColor property, instead BackgroundView in your custom cell needs to be assigned to - new UIVIew() (which has the background set)

UIView backgroundView = new UIView();
backgroundView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(Resources.CinemaListingCellBackground);
BackgroundView = backgroundView;